# Sql syntax error in dropping tabels

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I am using phpMyadmin as a database and I can't drop the tables ...how to spot the syntax error?

```
<?php       
include 'dbconnect.php';  //connect to DB  
//Droping The tables  
$dropping = @mysql_query('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rents, criticise, writesIn, writenIn, translated, reads, worksIn, inStock, playsIN, store, genre, employee, newspaper, customer, critic, language, actor, film, city ;'); 
if (!$dropping) {   
  exit('<p>Error dropping the tables<br />'.   
      'Error: ' . mysql_error() . '</p>');   
}       
if ($dropping) {   
  echo 'everything went just fine dropping the tables<br>';   
}
```

Comment: Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'reads,worksIn,inStock,playsIN,store,genre,employee,newspaper,customer,critic,lan' at line 1

Comment: *phpMyadmin as a database* no phpmyadmin is not a database! try to understand what you did on php and sql (and no, its not the same!)

Comment: remove semicolon from city ;');

Answer (score 1):

`reads` is a [reserved MySQL keyword](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html). You need to enclose it in backticks:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rents, criticise, writesIn, writenIn, translated, `reads`, worksIn, inStock, playsIN, store, genre, employee, newspaper, customer, critic, language, actor, film, city
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$dropping = @mysql_query('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS rents, criticise, writesIn, writenIn, translated, `reads`, worksIn, inStock, playsIN, store, genre, employee, newspaper, customer, critic, language, actor, film, city  ');
```

remove the semicolon `;` and use backticks for `reads` as its a keyword

Comment: Semicolon is a delimiter which will not cause any error at the end;